# Is there anything like method/function sentinels in C++/C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, sentinel

In Objective-C you can say something like:

```
NSArray *anArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:obj,obj2, nil];
```

In case you are not familiar with objective-c it is saying I want an object of type of NSArray, anArray, and I want to call the method arrayWithObjects and then it acts as a sentinel and accepts as many parameters (which in this case are objects) until it reaches nil.

Is there any way to achieve something like this:

```
createObjects(o1,o2,o3,o4,-1);
```

Where the method of function can accept as many parameters until it reaches some key value?

Now, I am aware you can do sentinel stuff in C and C++, but is there a way to provide something like this to a method like they do in Objective-C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a [variadic function](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Functions.html) and use a sentinel to locate the last real argument.

However, in C++, this is usually a bad idea because variadic functions are not type safe.  It's preferred in C++ to put the elements you want to pass into a container, array, or class object of some kind and then pass that to the function.  It's much less error-prone and much easier to verify.

Comment: Thanks, I had did not know about <stdarg.h> will look into.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [varargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varargs.h#.3Cvarargs.h.3E).